# Swift: error while saving video data from url

Tags: ios, swift, video, camera, save

I have the following code for saving a recorded video:

```
func saveVideo() -> Void {
        guard let url = self.videoUrl else {
            Logger.shared.log(.video, .error, "error video url invalid")
            return
        }
        
        let homeDirectory = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory(), isDirectory: true)
        let fileUrl = homeDirectory.appendingPathComponent(self.adId.toString()).appendingPathComponent("video-clip").appendingPathComponent(UUID.init().uuidString, isDirectory: false).appendingPathExtension("mov")
        
        Logger.shared.log(.video, .debug, "saving video to: \(fileUrl)")
        
        self.savedVideoUrl = fileUrl
        
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            try data.write(to: fileUrl, options: .atomicWrite)
        } catch {
            Logger.shared.log(.video, .error, "error saving video: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
    }
```

In here `self.videoUrl` is the `url` of the recorded video from camera and is initialized from the delegate method: `func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])`

The problem is that when the `saveVideo()` method executes, it gives an error:

```
[878     ] 13:22:16.045 | video | Main thread | error saving video: The folder “4A601A28-C4EB-405E-8110-6D01965D5920.mov” doesn’t exist.
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with this code. If the file does not exist then how do we have to create the file first and then write the data to it?

Comment: You need an actual folder path like example `var/root/myvids/` not some `UUID` number. Use a file manager app / tool to check the folder name and path of your video file, then test that path in your code.

Comment: @VC.One the intention is to save the video to a file with random UUID name. This is to avoid overwriting and existing file.

Comment: Even if that, all I'm saying is make sure your code can first save a file at the basic code level. When or If successful, then you can check if this UUID version of your code is also actually pointing to the same folder. The error says _"folder doesn't exist" but as you know `.mov` is for file type not folder name so somehow your compiler thinks `...D5920.mov` is the folder name (but I think you wanted it as file name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I had a similar task days ago (ie. downloading a video, regardless of the url source (local or remote) and then saving it locally).

I did an experiment using your function.

**See github repo, with working sample and applied fix to your function** https://github.com/glennposadas/AVFoundation-SaveLocal

What you're doing wrong is the way you provide the URL path for the new file.

EDIT: I think you need first to create your folder path. My `fileUrl` works because the path exists.

This way, it works (.mp4 or .mov, either way):

```
let fileUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
            .first!
            .appendingPathComponent("\(UUID.init().uuidString).mp4")
```

And it has a path (if you're going to print it):

```
/Users/myusername/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/812428A5-0893-43BE-B343-B23E9F13D4AA/data/Containers/Data/Application/E278E093-BE29-410B-9C5D-810BD0F968F8/Documents/F227C8B5-5D8D-42B0-8205-3ADAD0DD38F5.mp4
```

---

Meanwhile, your fileUrl:

```
    let homeDirectory = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory(), isDirectory: true)
    let fileUrl = homeDirectory
        .appendingPathComponent("someId")
        .appendingPathComponent("video-clip")
        .appendingPathComponent(UUID.init().uuidString, isDirectory: false)
        .appendingPathExtension("mov")
```

gives the path:

```
/Users/myusername/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/812428A5-0893-43BE-B343-B23E9F13D4AA/data/Containers/Data/Application/570D3CFA-3C44-41A5-A642-C79E5590D16E/someId/video-clip/5B1C9C98-C9EA-40D2-805C-B326466837E6.mov
```

---

EDIT: To fix the issue of missing file in your document every time you build your project, then see the changes in the repo I provided above. I added a fix for retrieving the video file from the document folder.

So basically how you should retrieve the file is you only save the `fileName`, because every run of the build produces a different `filePath`.

Comment: I tried this and the saving of video is now working. But when the app is closed and opened again and I try to retrieve the data, it is not found. I am the last path component of then following the same pattern to regenerate the complete path.